# Custom UITableViewController issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, xib

So I created a subclass of UITableViewController and have the xib,h,m files for this controller. but when I add a UIView or a UITableViewController to my main.storyboard it will not let me set my new subclass as the custom class.

Ive been trying to get this working for about 3 days now, watching youtube videos, reading tutorials and I can't seem to find anything similar to what Im trying to do.

Im trying to create a table with header and search bar that has everything self contained, including datasets.

Comment: Almost every bit of info prior to the "Problem:" paragraph has nothing to do with your actual problem. Remove all of the unnecessary info and keep the focus of your question on the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your class is a subclass of UITableViewController When you set it as the custom class of an UITableViewController object in the storyboard.

1: MySubClassOfTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController
[image: IT]

2: Find the UITableViewController object in the storyboard
[image]

3: Set Custom Class of the UITableViewController object to MySubClassOfTableViewController
[image]

Comment: Your not allowed to use a subclass of UITableViewController?

Comment: If you are using UITableViewController, make sure you are setting your subclass of UITableViewController to the UITableViewController object in the storyBoard.

Comment: Im sorry, I'm quite new to iOS. I think i realize my issue now. Controllers are entire windows and what I want is a view. So I can resize it or move it. Ill try this as soon as I get back to the computer. Thanks!

Comment: that was my problem, thanks for all the help. For anyone else with this issue. this video was helpful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP7YvdlnHfA